# How to display pagination for WooCommerce products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pagination

I have written this code to display WooCommerce products

```
<div class="products-container container mb-4">

<div class="products-filter-section mt-3">
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>
</div>

<?php
while (have_posts()) :
    the_post();
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="product card shadow-lg mb-4">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="card-img-top image border-0 p-0" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="body card-body">
            <h3 class="h6 mb-1 title"><a class="fw-bold" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php
               if(get_field('hide_product_author_name', 'options') != '1') {
            ?>
                <div class="author">By <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="footer card-footer border-0 pt-0 bg-white d-flex flex-wrap">
            <div class="info align-items-center flex-grow-1">
                <div class="price">
                    <?php if ($product->get_sale_price()) : ?>
                        <?php
                           if(get_field('hide_product_author_name', 'options') != '1') {
                        ?>
                        <span class="original text-decoration-line-through fw-bold me-1"><?php echo wc_price($product->get_regular_price()); ?></span>
                        <?php
                           }
                        ?>
                        <span class="with-off fw-bold"><?php echo wc_price($product->get_sale_price()); ?></span>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="original fw-bold"><?php echo wc_price($product->get_regular_price()); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex rate">
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                        if ($i < round($product->get_average_rating())) {
                            echo '<span class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-star"></span>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<span class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-star text-secondary"></span>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                       if(get_field('hide_product_rate', 'options') != '1') {
                    ?>
                    (<?php echo $product->get_rating_count(); ?>)
                    <?php
                       }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                   if(get_field('hide_product_sale_count', 'options') != '1') {
                ?>
                <div class="sale"><?php echo $product->get_total_sales(); ?> Sales</div>
               <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="align-items-end d-flex gap-2 action ms-auto">

                <?php
                   if(get_field('preview_link')) {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_field('preview_link') ); ?>" class="btn rounded px-3 preview" target="_blank">Preview</a>
                <?php
                   }
                ?>
                <?php
                   if(get_field('hide_product_add_to_cart', 'options') != '1') {
                ?>
                <?php
                $product_id = $product->get_id();
                $add_to_cart_url = wc_get_checkout_url() . '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id;
                ?>
                       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="btn rounded add-to-cart">
                           <span class="mdi mdi-cart-plus mdi-18px"></span>
                       </a>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have also written this code for the pagination of my products

```
function custom_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $pagination = paginate_links(array(
        'base'      => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'   => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => true,
        'prev_text' => '<span class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-chevron-left"></span>',
        'next_text' => '<span class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-chevron-right"></span>',
        'type'      => 'array',
        'mid_size'  => 3,
        'end_size'  => 1
    ));

    if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) :
        ?>
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <?php foreach ($pagination as $page_link) : ?>
                <li class="page-item <?php echo strpos($page_link, 'current') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php echo str_replace('page-numbers', 'page-link', $page_link); ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;
}
```

I have 10 products, but when I set the number of posts to 2 in WordPress settings and want my products to be displayed on 5 pages, nothing happens and the pagination is not displayed. Thank you for your help and tell me what is wrong with my code